# Motion To Absolve Users W/ Rep on Other Sites From "Are You A Robot" Questions

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

I have 2k rep on history.se, yet I still get the "are you a robot" message on other sites. I propose we eliminate that question for individuals with rep over 500 on any site.

Answer (score 1):

This is [status-by-design](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-by-design) and is likely to be [status-declined](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined).

[Why is Captcha necessary for high rep users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3346?rq=1)

[I'm not a robot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143455/i-am-not-a-robot)